# bcp export for unicode data

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am using bcp command in sql server to export data generated from a query to .csv file with the help of following command

*xp_cmdshell bcp EXEC .DBO.   QUERYOUT  -U  -P  /c /t, -T -S *

It is working fine and exporting data as expected but now we have a column which contain multilingual data and during exporting with above command data in csv file shows as "????????".

After doing some googling I found some other switch like -w to be used for unicode character but this option is creating unicode file and doesnot open in excel properly(columns are not separted by comma(,))

Can anybody help me if I am missing anything?

Comment: I am really stucked here and not able to find any solution. can anybody help me please

Answer (score 3):

`/t,` is not correct.  It should read `-t,` to set the field delimeter.  And `-w` is the correct flag for unicode.  Also I don't think -U/-P is used with -T.

```
bcp AdventureWorks2012..myTestUniCharData out C:\myTestUniCharData-w.Dat -w -t, -T
```

See the examples area in the following tech note:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188289.aspx

Comment: Have you tried it from the command line instead of `xp_cmdshell`? Also, with `-w` I don't think you need `/c`.  Also -U & -P are used if you do not use '-T' Have you gotten this to work with out the Unicode multilingual column?

Answer (score 2):

try using -w -T only.
don't add a field delimeter

Answer (score 1):

Using `-w` switch produces a file with UTF16 format, which is not easy to work with.

If your special characters are covered by [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) characters, then use the switches `-C -c` in your bcp command. `-C` makes a ISO 8859-1 file.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think "/c" or "/t" are the correct switches. see the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility): it should be -c or in your case -w for unicode. try from the cmd line using:

`bcp AdventureWorks2012.dbo.myTestUniCharData IN C:\temp\logs\ex170112.log -w  -S
 localhost\SQLEXPRESS -T`

you could also use a format file (.fmt) to tell it to format certain columns. see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/create-a-format-file-sql-server).

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me to import unicode from text file:

```
bcp dbo.MyTable in unicode-input.txt -S localhost -T -d EWBKonfig -C 65001 -c -t, -r '0x0A'
```